# Google analytics with a Chrome Web store packaged app

Tags: google-analytics, chrome-web-store

I have a couple of small packaged apps on the Chrome Web Store (that's packaged, not hosted, so I'm not hosting anything myself). I was wondering whether I can still use Google Analytics, and how to test whether it's working before publishing the app.

I'm guessing the answer might be no, because their [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/faq#faq-app-06) just says this:

"Can I use Google Analytics?
Yes. **Hosted apps** use Google Analytics just like any other website does. For help on using analytics in packaged apps (and extensions), see this tutorial."

Anyone know if there's a way around this?

***Resolution***

Followed the advice from the answer, but with a couple of small differences.  First, I did not modify in any way the code that I copied from GA.  Second, I pasted my GA ID in the app publishing form in my developer dashboard (go to developer dashboard, click edit for the app in question, then find the GA field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this might help: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_analytics.html

Comment: I saw that, I think it only applies to hosted apps.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: As far as i know it doesn't, you can use it for non hosted apps as well. Why dont you give it a try? :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently submitted an app and found that there is a text field for adding your Google Analytics code.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the new way of doing things.

Comment: This fields adds analytics to your webstore page but not to your app.